# Create event frequency graph from a datetime column in google spreadsheet

Tags: datetime, charts, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet containing a column of datetime values. There can be as many as 10 values that occur on a common date (at different times). Is it possible to create a graph that shows frequency of "events per day" such that the x axis is a date and the y axis is a numerical value from 0 to 10? There doesn't appear to be anything in the chart wizard that resembles this idea and my knowledge of spreadsheets is just about nil...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but I can't say I'm impressed by the results. If your column of datetime values starts in A2, please insert in B2 `=int(A2)` and in C2:

```
=if(B1=B2,1+C1,1)
```

and copy both down to suit. You might want to add an earlier date in B1.